# Prevent all spin icon spinning when click

Tags: reactjs

I am wondering if I could stop all spin to appear when only one delete button is click? Right now when I click on one of the delete buttons, all the spinners appear on all the delete buttons which should have been only the delete button that is performing the action. How should get this to work? Here is my code:

```
 <ul class="list-group">
            <h5>Schedules</h5>
            {scheduleData.map(items => {
                return (
                    <li key={items._id} class="list-group-item">
                        {moment(items.startdate).format('MMMM DD, YYYY')}{' '}
                        <span style={{marginRight: '0.2rem', marginLeft: '0.2rem'}}>
                            to
                        </span>
                        {moment(items.enddate).format('MMMM DD, YYYY')}{' '}
                        <span style={{float: 'right'}}>
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-primary"
                                onClick={event => deleteSchedule(event, items._id)}
                            >
                                {' '}
                                {loading && <i className="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i>}
                                &nbsp;Delete
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                );
            })}
        </ul>
```

Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that loading is a Boolean variable you set true in `deleteSchedule`, to achieve the result you have to create a loading parameter for every entry.
IMO the best approach would be to create an indipendent element in which you set `loading` with useState hook. You should pass `deleteSchedule` to this element and then when button is clicked it should call `setLoading(true)` and call `deleteSchedule`.
Other option would be to create a loading list and insert the id of the element which button was clicked in this list then loading would become `loading.includes(items._id)`.
Or you could iterate scheduleData and add loading attribute to every element.